# Android Studio - How to apply update patch 2.0 when no JVM is found on a 64bit windowns 10?

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

I recently tried to update my IDE from 1.1 to 2.2 Preview 3 and even though I had the newest 64bit jdk (jdk1.8.0.92) installed and referenced over the JAVA_HOME environment variable on my windows 10, as soon as i I opened the patch zip-file and ran the studio.exe, the program said that I did not have the right version of jvm installed.

**SOLUTION:** After searching a lot here over stackoverflow and tryed many of the ideas posted heres, i found the solution. It was so simple and obvious that i feelt i must share it with you guys. We all did everything right setting the JAVA_HOME to **C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_92** This was not the problem.

The **problema was** that in the patch zip file, there is also a .exe-file called **studio64.exe** After running that, it updates just fine. No need to do anything else.

[zip patch file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MfuZ.png)